# HQL not working with H2

Tags: hql, h2

I am implementing a unit test using the H2 embedded database.  When I insert an entry in a table, I am able to retrieve the entry using a native SQL query, but not with an HQL query. A find by the primary key also works through the JPA EntityManager interface. I am using Hibernate as the persistence provider.

Configuration:

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="false" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"    />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:persistenceUnitName="AMgSAdapter" p:packagesToScan="com.hcsc.amgs.adapter.domaindto">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.hcsc.amgs.adapter.dao.hibernate.interceptor.AuditableFieldInterceptor" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Test Case:

```
 @Test
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void getVasPolicyMatchesTest() {
        Application application = TestDataCreationUtil.createApplication();
        entityManager.persist(application.getX834EnrollmentApplicationTransaction());
        entityManager.persist(application);
        List<Application> matches = new ArrayList<Application>();
        Query q = simpleQueryHQL();
        matches= q.getResultList();
        Application findApp = entityManager.find(Application.class, application.getId()); // this works
        Assert.assertTrue(matches.size() > 0);
    }

private Query simpleQueryHQL() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("Select app From Application app", Application.class);
}

private Query simpleQuerySQL() {
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * from Application", Application.class);
}
```

No exceptions are thrown, the test case fails for simpleQueryHQL() and passes for simpleQuerySQL()

Comment: Try "SELECT app From Application app" [Case Sensitivity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-casesensitivity)

Comment: Still failed after changing HQL as above

Comment: You're only returning a query in the first one... To get results ... List<Application> results = simpleQueryHQL().getResultList();

Comment: I'm calling getResultList().  I just edited the code to make it a little more readable.  I just swap simpleQueryHQL() and simpleQuerySQL in the test case and it passes for the SQL version and fails for HQL.

Comment: If you could post a bit more readable example I might be able to help you pin down the problem... Create a [gist](http://gist.github.com)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/504157d10c3fa916b5da